# Windows compact framework support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: .net, ssl, https, windows-ce

Is there a way to do the HTTPS communication over SSL protocol TLS 1.1 and above ?
Thanks.

Comment: We use bouncy castle for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you are using .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5 compact framework, but the MSDN article below appears to be what you need. Mentions .NET 2.0 CF and Visual Studio 2005 (which is what I develop on WinCE with).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738067.aspx